# Excel export issue - from Jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, jakarta-ee, struts2, datatables, struts2-jquery

I'm trying to excel export from popup window(jquery UI Dialog).I have java class method with response type content-disposition attachment header.But its not downloading the excel sheet.

```
jQuery("#dialog-form").dialog ({ 
 autoOpen: false,
  height: 600,
  width: 700,
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  draggable: false, 
  buttons : {
"Export" : function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
     url : '<s:url action="list" method="export"/>',
     });
  } });
```

Java class :

```
public String export(){

--some backend calls.

httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-disposition",
      "attachment; filename="+filename+".xls");
      ServletOutputStream outputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
      outputStream.flush();
      return null;
    }
```

Console :

```
No result returned for action at null
```

Please advise why is this excel download is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors:

1. filename should be enclosed in double quotes, and `inline` should be used instead of `attachment`, if you want to open it in the browser instead of downloading it:

   ```
   httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-disposition", 
                                 "inline; filename=\""+filename+"\".xls");
   ```
2. You should always specify the `contentType`:

   ```
   httpServletResponse.setContentType(
           "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
   ```

   (or `application/vnd.ms-excel` for older Excel files);
3. from the Action you should return `NONE` instead of `null` (this is causing your error).

---

That said, you really don't have the need to use an Action like a Servlet ([like instead I had here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16654313/1654265)):

**just use a [Stream result](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/StreamResult.html)**, set the `ContentType` and the `ContentDisposition` in the `Struts.xml`, and return the InputStream to the page, [like described in this example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-download-file-example/).

Comment: Thanks for the hint using the "contentType". I still had the vnd.ms-excel but using a dialog within dataTables didn't allow me that any more.

Comment: You're welcome @leole. Feel free to upvote the answer if it helped