# How to read & open multiple file in one request using struts?

Tags: java, struts2

I have a requirement that, User will see the list of files in the page which is the list from directory. From there they will select multiple files and they click on view button. Then we need to read the corresponding files from Drive and need to open all the files which are all user has selected. I need to implement this using Struts2/servlet.

Comment: All that you have said is done by plain JavaScript and based on the power of your browser to handle multiple file uploading (IE 6, 7 and 8 doesn't support this feature). Apart from that, each file upload will fire a request to the server and will be handled separately.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza this is about multiple download from server, not multiple upload from client

Comment: What did you try? Nobody could understand what have you written until you post the code examples and clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I userstand the user sees the content of a directory which is located on the server, right?

Further, you display a list of files along with some selection method (checkboxes ?) which the user uses to select files and then clicks the view button.

If I am correct, you could use javascript to open a new tab/window or dialog (e.g. a jQuery dialog) which reads the file or its contents from the server. Just iterate over the selected entries in the list and pass them one by one to the JavaScript function that opens the tab/window/dialog.

Comment: Yes you are correct. we need to open the files using file selection.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you do want to

1. ***open each file*** in the client's browser, or
2. ***download each file*** to the client's file system, or
3. ***download an archive*** containing all the files to the client's file system;

In 1. or 2. you need to create multiple requests, [targeting multiple windows, using `target="_blank"`, or by AJAX, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16900840/1654265) .

By manipulating HttpResponse Header objects, you can instruct the browser when to open or download a file: `Content-Disposition: inline;` will try to open it inside the browser, while `Content-Disposition: attachment;` will perform the default operation (open with default desktop application, download, or ask if none of the previous was marked as default by the user)

Keep in mind that you may encounter several possible problems by opening or downloading multiple files at once; it could overload/crash the client, overload/crash the server, cause problem of bandwidth etc; what if the user choose 100 files ? You would open 100 tab, or 100 windows, or ask 100 times where to save each file, etc...

If you want to create a dynamic ZIP instead, [you can find a kick-off example on how to do it in Struts2 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16654313/1654265), (using an Action like a Servlet, and returning NONE); 
My files were from database, yours are from file system, but the code is the same.