# Generate xlsx file with POI in a zip

Tags: java, excel, struts2

I export data in an xlsx files with the POI Api and added they're in a Zip file. When I open the zip I do not have any xlsx files but three directories (docProps, xl and _rels) and 1 file [Content_Types] xml. I think it's the xlsx file's description, but I don't understand why.

Code :

```
public InputStream exportXlsx(List<MyObject> listeOfObject) throws IOException {

        ByteArrayOutputStream excelOutputStreamZip = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(excelOutputStreamZip);

        for (MyObject myObject : listeOfObject) {

            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet wsheet = wb.createSheet("mySheet");
            XSSFRow row = wsheet.createRow(0);
            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(myObject.getValue1());

            // Create all sheet and cell....

            // Write WB conntent in outputStream
            wb.write(excelOutputStreamZip);

            addEntry(zip, myObject.getFileName(), excelOutputStreamZip);
        }

        InputStream inputStreamZipByte = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                ((ByteArrayOutputStream) excelOutputStreamZip).toByteArray());
        zip.close();

        return inputStreamZipByte;

    }

    public void addEntry(OutputStream zip, String filename, ByteArrayOutputStream os) {

        byte[] bytes = os.toByteArray();

        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
        Date d = new Date();
        entry.setTime(d.getTime());
        try {
            ((ZipOutputStream) zip).putNextEntry(entry);
            ((ZipOutputStream) zip).write(bytes);
            ((ZipOutputStream) zip).closeEntry();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Can't read the file !", e);
        } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
            log.error("Bad format !", cce);
        }

    }
```

This code is write in a service which is inject in a Struts2 action.

struts.xml :

```
<action name="*MyAction" class="com.omb.view.action.myAction" method="{1}">
    <result name="export" type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">application/zip</param>
        <param name="inputName">inputStreamZipByte</param>
        <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="myZip.zip"</param> 
        <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a part of my solution, but now I have another problem :

the problem for  the inital post was in the handling of streams. Because I used the same outputStream for the Zip and the Workbook. Solution was created a new ByteArrayOutpuStream for each workbook.

```
// Write WB conntent in outputStream    
ByteArrayOutputStream wbOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
wb.write(wbOutputStream);    
addEntry(zip, myObject.getFileName(), wbOutputStream);    
wbOutputStream.close();
```

But...now the Zip file generated is corrupted...

Comment: If you want to dynamically add multiple files (xls, xlsx, and so on) inside a ZIP from Struts2, [take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16654313/1654265), it may help.

Comment: thank you  Andrea, I solved my problem with the post.

Comment: am also getting the same error when using JSF and Spring I too dont understand why

Answer (score 0):

The xlsx file is a zip file. You should check the MIME type appropriate for the `contentType` parameter of the result. See [What is a correct mime type for docx, pptx etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc)

Comment: Ok thank's for your help. I tried to generete a set of xlsx files and put them in a zip file that will be downloaded by the user. So should i change the contentType in the struts2 config file ? Even if would like have a zip file ?

Answer (score -1):

Just write the workbook to BytearrayInputStream then convert into byte array
Use that byte array in ZipOutPutStream

This one works for me ..........................

> response.setContentType("application/zip");
>
> response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\""+fileName+".zip\"");
>
> workBook = getWorkbook(displayList, cfgType);
>
> ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>
> ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
>
> ByteArrayOutputStream fileBaos = new >ByteArrayOutputStream();
>
> zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("Test.xlsx"));
>
> workBook.write(fileBaos);
>
> zos.write(fileBaos.toByteArray());
>
> zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("Test1.xlsx"));
>
> zos.write(fileBaos.toByteArray());
>
> fileBaos.close();
>   zos.close();
>
> response.getOutputStream().write(baos.toByteArray());
>   response.flushBuffer();