# How to download a zip file in a struts2 application

Tags: java, file, struts2, zip

I am facing a problem while enabling zip file download in struts2 application.

here is my jsp page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<s:url id="fileDownload" namespace="/" action="Download" ></s:url>

<h4>Download file - <s:a href="%{fileDownload}">MyFile.zip</s:a>
</h4>
```

and here is my action class

```
public class DownloadAction implements Action
{
    List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE = "C:\\Users\\Ankush\\Desktop\\MyFile.zip";
    private String SOURCE_FOLDER ;
    private FileOutputStream fos;
    private InputStream fileInputStream;
    public FileOutputStream getFos() {
        return fos;
    }

    public void setFos(FileOutputStream fos) {
        this.fos = fos;
    }

    private ZipOutputStream zos;
    public String  execute()
    {
        Map<String, Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();

        System.out.println("DOWNLOAD ACTION path="+(session.get("BASIC_PATH").toString()+session.get("username").toString()+"\\"+session.get("course_Name").toString()));
        this.setSOURCE_FOLDER(session.get("BASIC_PATH").toString()+session.get("username").toString()+"\\"+session.get("course_Name").toString());
        System.out.println("ORIGINOL PATH="+"E:\\Z800\\WebAuthoringData\\EMMRC\\Ankush\\Raag_Durga");
        this.generateFileList(new File(this.getSOURCE_FOLDER()));
        this.zipIt(OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public InputStream getFileInputStream() {
        return fileInputStream;
    }



    public ZipOutputStream getZos() {
        return zos;
    }

    public void setZos(ZipOutputStream zos) {
        this.zos = zos;
    }

    /**
     * Zip it
     * @param zipFile output ZIP file location
     */
    public void zipIt(String zipFile){

     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

     try{

        fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

        System.out.println("Output to Zip : " + zipFile);

        for(String file : this.fileList){

            System.out.println("File Added : " + file);
            ZipEntry ze= new ZipEntry(file);
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);

            fileInputStream = 
                       new FileInputStream(SOURCE_FOLDER + File.separator + file);

            int len;
            while ((len = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        }
         fileInputStream.close();
        fos.flush();
        zos.flush();

        zos.closeEntry();
        //remember close it
        zos.close();
        fos.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }catch(IOException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();   
    }

   }
```

and my struts.xml for this

```
<action name="Download" class="com.cdac.action.DownloadAction">

            <result name="error">/WEB-INF/jsps/error.jsp</result>


    <result name="success" type="stream">
      <param name="contentType">application/zip</param>
      <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
      <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="MyFile.zip"</param>
      <param name="bufferSize">2048</param>
    </result>
    </action>
```

and error log

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:626)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:215)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:105)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:182)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:123)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsps.error_jsp._jspService(error_jsp.java:82)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:166)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Nov 18, 2014 3:54:05 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:534)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:452)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:166)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:626)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:215)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:105)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:182)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:123)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsps.error_jsp._jspService(error_jsp.java:82)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    ... 32 more

Nov 18, 2014 3:54:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/web-authoring-tool] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:443)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:914)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:574)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please anybody help me as i don't know how to fix this issue and probably i may be doing some silly mistake but i can't figure it out. Please help me . i will be very thankful to you!

Comment: Don't close stream that you will send to client.

Comment: I did it according to you . this has removed the exception but still the downloaded zip file is broken

Comment: Your suggestion really helped me Sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write in the client File System like that; in your case, your server is in your machine, but don't get fooled, it's a server path, not a client one. You need to write on the response.

You can't use both Struts2 result and writing in the OutputStream together: when manually forging the response, you must bypass the framework convention, and return the result by yourself. The correct result for this case is is `Action.NONE`:

```xml
<action name="Download" class="com.cdac.action.DownloadAction" />
```

```java
public String execute(){
    /* 
    do your stuff
    */
    return NONE;
}
```

You're lucky, [here is a kick off example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16654313/1654265) I've written long time ago, explaining the whole thing (including the need to deal with duplicate filenames in the same ZIP).

Also try using `Content-Length` properly (to let the browser draw a realistic progress-bar).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but its not working. Mentioning Return type as NONE does nothing and now my file is not even download

Comment: You need to alter your code too, as in the answer I've linked

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. I have done it know with your help. Thank you very much for showing me the way.